# Hyperlink can't be clicked under div

Tags: html, css

I've tried experimenting with `z-index` and `position:relative` but I can't seem to get this to work.

I've made it so once you hover your mouse over the images, a hyperlink appears, but for some reason you can't click the hyperlink. Can someone please show me how to bring it to the front?

Here's my code:

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 1.250em;
  margin-bottom: 2.188em;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.caption::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.imageh:hover+.caption::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.imageh {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.caption__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
  transition: transform .35s ease-out;
}

.imageh:hover+.caption .caption__overlay {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__media {
  padding-top: 130px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="imageh"></span>
<div class="caption">
  <img src="http://bsnscb.com/data/out/78/27073638-free-farm-wallpapers.jpg" />
  <div class="caption__overlay">
    <div class="caption__overlay__content">
      <h1 style="text-align:center" class="caption__media"><a style="color:white;" href="artists.html">OUR ARTISTS</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the span element on hover which is a sibling to the image container(making it hard to avoid flickering during hover). You can just hover on the caption container div itself. See sample code below

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 1.250em;
  margin-bottom: 2.188em;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
   
}

.caption::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.imageh {
/*  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;*/
}

.caption__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
  transition: transform .35s ease-out;
 
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__media {
  padding-top: 130px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="imageh"></span>
<div class="caption">
  <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" />
  <div class="caption__overlay">
    <div class="caption__overlay__content">
      <h1 style="text-align:center" class="caption__media"><a style="color:white;" href="artists.html">OUR ARTISTS</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep everything as is except two things. Set the element with class "imageh" with z-index 0 and the element with class "caption__overlay__content" with z-index 1.